# Azure DevOps CD Pipeline Multi-stage deployment using YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am running my CD pipeline for multi-stage deployment (DEV, UAT, PROD).

I want to deploy my artifact based on changes in particular branch. If the reference branch is `refs/heads/develop` then only DEV stage will deploy my artifact to dev environment, if the reference branch is `refs/heads/release/` then only UAT and PROD stages will deploy my artifact to dev and prod environments.

As the pipeline is started from DEV and checking the source branch, if the source branch is not `refs/heads/develop` then DEV stage is getting skipped, so rest of the stages also skipped.

**YAML**

```
- stage: DEV
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'))
  displayName: DEV Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: IIS_DEV_Deployment

- stage: UAT
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
  displayName: UAT Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: IIS_UAT_Deployment

- stage: PROD
  condition: succeeded()
  displayName: PROD Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: IIS_PROD_Deployment
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Would question why use this approach? One of the points of YAML multi-stage deployments is to ensure the same artifact is consistently deployed throughout each stage. By doing this you are skipping the stages required for your pipeline to execute. Would recommend one pipeline delivering the artifact to each stage. If you are insisted on doing this would recommend a separate pipeline for each one with independent triggers.

Answer (score 0):

It because the `and(succeeded()` condition, if DEV Job skipped is not succeeded.

Update the `release` condition to:

```
and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
```